# Excluding LEFT OUTER JOINS in an Oracle SQL QUERY if a COLUMN on base table = 'N'

Tags: sql, oracle12c, query-performance, sql-execution-plan

Below you'll see a simple JOIN statement of 5 base tables, I'm trying to excluded the two LEFT OUTER JOIN statements tables (**dandm_emi_cae_statement_links, geod_us_cae_statement_links**) from the SQL statement if the column **geod_exclude_us_y** in the **JMD_UDG_DISTRIBUTION** table is equal 'N'.

Currently the below statement in the SQL PLAN still looks at these tables, how do I stop it from doing the LEFT OUTER JOIN' if the table **JMD_UDG_DISTRIBUTION** column **geod_exclude_us_y = 'N'**?

```
SELECT lfu.*
FROM JMD_UDG_DISTRIBUTION jud  
JOIN dm_lifeline_file_usages lfu 
    ON  lfu.group_id = jud.GROUP_SURR_ID 
JOIN dm_lifeline_file_ips lfi 
    ON  lfi.usage_group_id = lfu.group_id 
    AND lfi.lfu_surr_id = lfu.surr_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dandm_emi_cae_statement_links dnm 
    ON  jud.geod_exclude_us_y = 'Y' 
    AND dnm.cae=lfi.cae_number 
LEFT OUTER JOIN geod_us_cae_statement_links gucs 
    ON  jud.geod_exclude_us_y = 'Y' 
    AND gucs.cae_number=lfi.cae_number
```

Comment: I don't thnik that you can actually force the database to not perform this or that join. As far as concerns, you should trust the database to do the right decision in terms of execution plan based on the query that you hand it over.

Comment: I guess I am not understanding what your question is. Could you clarify? As written, the two left outer joins do nothing as no values are used from those tables.

Answer (score 0):

Of course.  The rules for `LEFT JOIN` are:

- All the rows that match the `ON` condition.
- All rows in the *first* table when there is no match in the second.

So, a condition on the *first* table in `ON` has no impact on the results.  That is not strictly true.  There *is* a weird sort of impact.  The columns from the second table -- even for otherwise matching rows -- are `NULL`.

So, you want to filter in the `WHERE` clause.  Move `jud.geod_exclude_us_y = 'Y'` from the `ON` clauses to:

```
WHERE jud.geod_exclude_us_y = 'Y'
```

Comment: I'm sorry when I move jud.geod_exclude_us_y = 'Y' to the WHERE clause, I don't get any records back when I should at least get records back from the THREE BASE TABLES Gordon Linoff

Comment: @ShaunKinnair . . . Based on your question, perhaps the comparison should be to `'N'` and not to `'Y'`.